# How to distinguish Xsun from Xorg, programmatically?

Tags: xorg

VendorString() doesn't work, it's always Sun Microsystems, even if it is Xorg built for Solaris.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep vendor
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    10601901
```

This is xorg-server 1.6.1 on Linux.  Hopefully XOrg and XSun on Solaris will differ here.

To output these two fields, `xdpyinfo` calls the [`ServerVendor` macro](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qlength) to determine the vendor, then parses the return of the [`VendorRelease` macro](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qlength) differently depending on what `ServerVendor` was.

By the way, what's `VendorString()`?  I don't have a function or macro by that name...

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a little hacky, but if you look at the list of extensions returned from Xsun and Xorg you should see that Xorg has a few extra XFree86-derived extensions.

`xdpyinfo` can be used to list the extensions via the command-line to check for differences; programmatically you can use `XListExtensions()` or `XQueryExtension()`.

*(I haven't got a Xsun X Server to hand but I'm pretty sure when I've looked in the past they have differed quite abit).*

Comment: Only Xsun will have Adobe-DPS - Sun is not including that in our Xorg port.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
Oops, VendorRelease() string it is.
Anyway, unfortunately we cannot bet on this string. It changes often enough to have a trouble, for Xsun as well as for Xorg. I have found a solution working (hopefully) for them and for various other (derived) servers like Xvfb, Xnest etc.

Xsun does use a third value in an array of the keysyms for KP_ (numpad) keycodes. Xorg uses 1-st or 2-nd. A sniffer should first, obtain a keycode for a KP_ keysym, for instance XK_KP_7,
second, sniff what is in the XKeycodeToKeysym(d,keycode, [0-3]). Our XK_KP_7 will be on the index 2 for Xsun.

Comment: Wow, that's feels like an even uglier hack than Dave's solution, but as long as it works... !